# Why won't outlook/exchange resolve this particular user

Tags: email, exchange-2007, outlook, resolve

This email address is a domain email address:

*callcentre@domain.co.uk*

I have no issues sending emails to any other *email@domain.co.uk*. I've narrowed the problem down to the resolving of the domain name.

I.E: If I type in *callcentre@domain.co.uk* outlook will get the user from exchange and load (what it thinks) is a resolved email address. I know this because as I click send, *callcentre@domain.co.uk* turns into Call Centre (The accounts display name).

It's not, however, resolving to the right address. It is instead trying to send to something like:

**IMCEAEX-_O=FIRST+20ORGANIZATION_OU=First+20administrative+20group_cn=Recipients_cn=CallCentre@domain.co.uk**

(I had replaced actual domain with *domain*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that a mailbox with the alias 'callcentre' was deleted and then recreated, or maybe it used to be a mailbox, and now it's a distribution group?  So now, it's got a different LegacyExchangeDN attribute than the one that Outlook has cached.  If it works in OWA but not Outlook, that's what's happening.

Try this:  When you start to type 'callcentre' in the to: field, it should be showing you a MRU dropdown from which you can select the whole address.  Instead of clicking on that address, or pressing tab, click the 'X' next to the entry in the list.  This should clear out that cached entry.  If that doesn't work, try creating a new Outlook profile from the mail control panel.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. Outlook uses the LegacyExchangeDN for internal recipients. This recipient was deleted and recreated but the Outlook nickname cache has the original recipient LegacyExchangeDN. Deleting the entry from the cache should resolve it.